# Adding value to rows of a specific column when a specific conditions is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the column ZIP which contains lots of ZIP Codes.

However, I get the source data in an .xlsx-file. In Excel this column is a number field.
That's why Excel ignores the 0 as the first character for ZIP codes which typically start with a zero.

Normally a ZIP code in my country has  five digits.

Now, I want to refill the zero in my dataframe column "ZIP" again. The rows with the missing zero's are easy to spot because they have 4 characters instead of 5.

```
2314
1234
1234
4322
1234
1234
4323
97862
43242
43212
43213
```

How can I add a '0' to all rows in the column "ZIP" where there are only for characters instead of the normal five?

I know that I could get a leading zero like this:

```
missing_zero = "0"
df['ZIP'] = missing_zero + df['ZIP'].map(str)
```

But this would add a zero to all the rows instead of just the rows with the missing zero.

I'd appreciate any insights on how to add the **where character length = 4 logic**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

```py
df['ZIP'] = df['ZIP'].apply(lambda x: '0' + str(x) if len(str(x)) == 4 else str(x))
print(df)

     ZIP
0  02315
1  01234
2  01234
3  12345
4  12345
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if your column is formatted as a string.

```
df['zip'].str.zfill(5)
```

Comment: Way better solution! didn't know of that option.